# Validity of variable in node.js with sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I do a select statement on sqlite3 in node.js. I'd like to have the result in the variable "data" which is defined outside the sqlite code block but it stays empty. Within the sqlite code block the data variable has the correct value. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

```js
    /* Client connects via socket.io */
    io.on('connection', function(client) {
        console.log('Client connected');

        /* Client needs data... */
        client.on('needData', function(fields) {
            var data = [];
            var sql_stmt = "SELECT ...";
            if(fs.existsSync(db_file)) {
                try {
                    var db = new sqlite3.Database(db_file);
                    db.all(sql_stmt, function(err, all) {
                        data = all;
                        console.log(data); //--> data has valid values
                    }); 
                    db.close();
                    console.log(data); //--> data is empty
                }
                catch(e) {
                    console.log("Error with database. Error: ", e); 
                }   
            }
            else {
                console.log("Database file not found.");
            }

            client.emit('data', data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: It's due to async nature, try to use promise or async module to get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happening just because of `asynchronous` nature of `Node.js` you can handle it with by `promises`

I recommend to use [waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall) method of [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) module

```
 var async=require('async');
  /* Client connects via socket.io */
  io.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client connected');

    /* Client needs data... */
    client.on('needData', function(fields) {
      async.waterfall([function(next) {
        var sql_stmt = "SELECT ...";
        if (fs.existsSync(db_file)) {
          try {
            var db = new sqlite3.Database(db_file);
            db.all(sql_stmt, function(err, all) {
            next(null,all)
            });
            db.close();
          } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error with database. Error: ", e);
            next();
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Database file not found.");
          next();
        }
      }], function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
      client.emit('data', data);
        }
      })
    });
  });
```